# Error when querying using Op.contain in sequelize.

Tags: sequelize.js

So I am working on a project for learning purposes.  I am getting the following error.

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: unrecognized token: "@"
    at Query.formatError (/mnt/c/Users/Mike/websites/Treehouse-FSJS-Project-10/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:423:16)
    at afterExecute (/mnt/c/Users/Mike/websites/Treehouse-FSJS-Project-10/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:119:32)
    at replacement (/mnt/c/Users/Mike/websites/Treehouse-FSJS-Project-10/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:19:31)
    at Statement.errBack (/mnt/c/Users/Mike/websites/Treehouse-FSJS-Project-10/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:16:21)
```

Below is my code for the query.

```
router.get('/book_detail/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    books
        .findAll({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id,
            },
            include: [
                {
                    model: loans,
                },
            ],
        })
        .then(book => {
            const patronList = []
            const loans = []
            book[0].dataValues.loans.map(patrons => {
                patronList.push(patrons.dataValues.patron_id)
                loans.push(patrons.dataValues)
                console.log(loans)
            })

            patrons
                .findAll({
                    where: {
                        id: {
                            [Op.contains]: patronList,
                        },
                    },
                })
                .then(patron => {
                    // console.log(patronList)
                    console.log(patron)
                    res.render('book_detail', { book, loans })
                })
        })
})
```

I should be able to see the patrons who have checked out this book. I am getting the correct id's as you can see in the query below.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `address`, `email`, `library_id`, `zip_code` FROM `patrons` AS `patrons` WHERE `patrons`.`id` @> 1, 3;
```

It seems to have to do with **Op.contains** but I guess I do not understand why this would not work correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the below query :

```
where: {
    id: {
        [Op.contains]: patronList,
    },
},
```

To

```
where: {
    id: patronList
},
```

As I can't see any use of the `contains` over here ,

> [Op.contains]: [1, 2]      // @> [1, 2] (PG array contains operator)
>
> You can use that for json array kind of field , but in your case it's
>   like primary key of table.

Comment: Ok this makes sense.  I was not sure if it would accept an array.  Thanks so much.